# In a home network, how do I ssh from a client to a host connected to a VPN?

Tags: ssh, networking, vpn, vnc

I have a Debian 11 box on my home network which I can ssh into and use vnc to access it like a regular desktop. I've installed a VPN on the host, but when I connect to the VPN on the host then logout of the ssh session, the VPN has disconnected when I log back in from the client. I guess the vpn client (in this case protonvpn) shuts off on logout, and anyway, how would I log back in if the host machine has a different ip address, one of many which can be allocated by the VPN?

How can I set the host to have internet access through a VPN, and still access it by ssh from a client on my home network? Note the client is not conencted to a VPN when logging into the host and is running Mint 20.3.

Comment: You can configure to ip addresses for your host and then always connect on the one setup for local traffic, and then on a nohup ssh session do the other VPN connecting.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but I'm stuck on how to implement this suggestion. Editing the connection with the network config gui, I can add an additional static address, which is listed with `ip a`. I've tried ssh to the new static address, I get a ..`port 22 no route to host` error. How do I apply one address to the ssh side, and the other to the vpn side of things?

Comment: You should search about "reverse ssh". It's a method as reliable as regular (forward) ssh, which is used to enable ssh connections in some pathological situations like dynamic ip assignment by ISP, or troublesome firewalls keeping port 22 closed. Note that the former case is similar to your own issue. The drawback is that the connection has to be initiated on the server. So in your case, "someone" will have to issue a command on your box at home to create the ssh tunnel. Fortunately, this someone can be a cron job.

Comment: Many thanks for that, reverse ssh could be useful, but I found another solution- I think it's the protonvpn software that's causing the trouble here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the VPN client software, in this case `protonvpn-cli` and the associated GUI application - it terminates once you are logged out of the ssh session for some reason.

In short, the solution is to manually connect to the VPN using OpenVPN through the network manager instead of using the `protonvpn-cli` or GUI. The connection will persist when logged out of an ssh session.

Remove the `protonvpn-cli` and gui software and make sure the killswitch configuration file (`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/pvpn-ipv6leak-protection`) is deleted otherwise there will be problems, more on that issue at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319033/internet-stops-working-after-installing-protonvpn). Login to the protonvpn website and download your preferred network configuration files to be imported to OpenVPN. It's important you use the OpenVPN credentials provided in your account, and not your usual login email and password, as this will not work with OpenVPN. In the network manager, click the plus icon, then "Import a saved VPN configuration". Enter the login credentials then connect.

In this example, my local machine is "mint" running Mint Una with Gnome desktop, the remote machine on my local network is "debian" running debian 11 with xfce4 desktop. Everything can be configured with ssh access from the local mint machine.

On mint, ssh into the remote machine:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 debian@ip-address
```

On debian start a vncserver:

```
vncserver
```

VNC into debian (using vinagre app)

```
vinagre localhost:1
```

Through the remote desktop, I can remove protonvpn as mentioned above, setup the manual connection, connect then logout. When I log back in, it's still connected to the VPN :) Happy days!